# how to close the div in DOM JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i shows the error where when i dd the li into my html. this li is covered the all the html section in my code. i dont know where i close the li

Comment: I_N_D_E_N_T_A_T_I_O_N L_O_O_K_S W_E_I_R_D.

Comment: Why are you using `document.createElement("div")` instead of `$("<div/>")`?

Comment: $("<div/>") but how its close . please denote my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<li />', {'class': 'liBullet'}).append(
    $('<div />', {'class': 'layerCheck'}).append(
        $('<input />', {id: layer.id, type: "checkbox"})
    )
).append(
    $('<label />', {'for': layer.id, text: layer.name})
).append(
    $('<div />', {id: 'legend' + layer.id, 'class': 'loadingLegend'})
).appendTo("#layer_list");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VvvbW/1/)

Comment: Thank you adeneo. Its wok fine. In the code i check my condition li and ul its not display the properly. can you help me